# Deploy SharePoint 2010 Custom Solution to 2013 SharePoint

Tags: 2013, migration, solution-package

I do not have much experience with SharePoint 2013 when it come to development, at least not yet.  I know that 2013 has both a 14 and 15 hive, which would lead me to think that you can put 2010 solutions on the 2013 environment.  I also know that SharePoint 2013 is running off of the 4.5 framework which would lead me to think the DLLs will not work anymore. I have read some articles which say that there is a compatibility mode which will allow for GAC deployment of 2010 solutions.  Can anyone tell me what I should watch out for when converting.  As a SharePoint developer, I think it would be better to just recreate the web parts in 2012 VS and repackage.

Can running the 2010 wsp in PowerShell to deploy to 2013 cause any issues I should be aware of?  Is it better to repackage and deploy?  Has anyone run into anything they did not expect by loading 2010 custom solutions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In SharePoint 2013, sites can be created either in SP 2010 mode or SP 2013 mode. So, SP 2010 compatible WSPs can be deployed to 14 hive by specifying the compatibility mode in SP 2013. Therefore a SP 2010 mode site will work properly. However, if the idea is to use SP 2013 based site, then the custom solutions should be upgraded. If you have VS 2012 or 2013 and Visual Studio Office Developer Tools installed then SP 2010 based solutions are automatically upgraded. That is Target Framework in Project properties and assembly versions are automatically updated. The assembly versions are automatically updated in files like.ascx controls. However, since SP 2013 uses 15 hive, references to `_layouts`, `controltemplates` etc need to be manually updated. For example, `/_layouts/images/NY.ExportVersionHistory/Excel_Small.png` will need to be updated to `/_layouts/15/images/NY.ExportVersionHistory/Excel_Small.png`. Similarly any reference to `~/_CONTROLTEMPLATES` will need to be changed to `~/_CONTROLTEMPLATES/15`. For more information please refer to following links:

http://www.sharepointnadeem.com/2013/12/sharepoint-2013-upgrade-from-sharepoint.html
http://www.sharepointnadeem.com/2013/12/sharepoint-2013-upgrade-sharepoint-2010.html

Comment: Thanks, great answer!  This is exactly what I thought.  I would assume that I need the solutions as well because of the reference changes.  I have not had a chance to look at the web parts my company is wanting me to convert.  I told them I need the solutions to make the conversions properly.  This is true, yes?  This was my assumption based off of my experience with 2007 to 2010 migration.  Thank you for your input!  Much appreciated!